# Mailto recipient limit

Tags: mailto

I am sending emails from my application using the mailto:

```
 Process.Start("mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" 
                        + body);
```

When I use this with a small number of email addresses (10-20) it works fine, but I am testing it with a larger number (100+) but some of the emails are not being added to the recipient list.

Is there a limit to the number of emails I can add in this way? and there is, whats the limit?

Comment: Do the body and the subject still get set? Which mail client are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a limit, it depends on the underlying email client that is registered for `mailto:` links.

Sending emails this way starts a new Windows process to open an email sending window, typically Microsoft Outlook. It could well be there is a limit to the number of recipients that Outlook will permit or the size of the mailto: string.

A possible workaround could be to create two or more email messages instead, each with 20 or less email addresses.

Alternatively, you may want to explore the `System.Mail.SmtpClient` class and consider sending mail directly from your application. Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The limit is whatever lmiit the server imposes. As in: no, SMTP has no limit, but servers dont like spammers. Staying below 20 is quite safe, below 10 normally totally ok.

Alternatively reconfigure your server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a question for C#. I believe you starting a new process with certain arguments so it is up-to the the email client's limit. It could be a limit of a standard URL Microsoft supports which I believe is ~2053 chars (try validating this).

**Edit:**

You may also want to try an alternative like:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;

// Send Mail
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("Server-IP");
client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string Address = "hotline.isp@abc;supportpl.ispit@bcd";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" + Address + "&subject=Support request&body=Dear Hotline,");
```