# Emailing to multiple receipents using mailto not working for more than 100 mails

Tags: mailto

We need to send mail to more than 100 emails and if it crosses certain limit, mailto link is not working. If it's only 10-50 mails, then there is no issue.

I tried using both , and ; but it's still not working. Can you please provide solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647310/mailto-recipient-limit. Check if it has been asked before posting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.